# Minimize Logging without Setting Bulk Logged

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, transaction-log

What is the best way to minimize an SQL transaction log without setting the database to simple recovery mode bulk logged?  I'm using Amazon, and the database does not allow bulk logging.  From what I've researched, the best way would be removing keys from large tables along with adjusting the auto-growth setting.  The data causing the size issues is all public, non-replicating, re-accessible data, so removing the keys wouldn't cause proprietary data loss after an event.  Can anyone confirm this solution as the best or offer an alternative?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removing keys from your tables does not sound like a good plan to me. This will likely remove your clustered indexes too which will cause all your queries to be far slower.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Admittedly, it's not the ideal, but until bulk logging is available, this may be the best solution.  The large tables are only accessed infrequently by the company, not by customers, so the speed of the queries isn't as important as it otherwise would be.